# Update Query with Trigger

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, sqlplus, oracle-apex

I have 2 tables  i-e (1)`Return_Invoice`  and (2)`product_warehouse` . i want to update the quantity column used in `Product_warehouse` once i enter the data in `Return_Invoice` table quantity column  i-e when i enter the value in `Quantity` column in `Return_Invoice` Table that `quantity` should be minus from `Quantity` column in `Product_Warehouse` Table.Any  query or Trigger for  this.

[image]

I have tried the following query but it do not works.

```
update product_warehouse 
set Product_Warehouse.Quantity = Product_Warehouse.Quantity - Return_Invoice.Quantity
where (Product_Warehouse.item_code = Return_Invoice.item_code)
```

Comment: Is it a must to use TRIGGER in this case? Can you use a query for this?

Comment: its up to you..if u know the query  i can adjust tht in trigger

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether the given trigger is your requirement:

```
create or replace
TRIGGER "WR_RETURN_INVOICE_UPDATE_TRG" 
AFTER UPDATE ON RETURN_INVOICE
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    UPDATE PRODUCT_WAREHOUSE
    SET QUANTITY=QUANTITY-:OLD.QUANTITY
    WHERE ITEM_CODE=:OLD.ITEM_CODE;   
END WR_RETURN_INVOICE_UPDATE_TRG;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your Item code in the place needed

```
    Create TRIGGER anUpdate ON dbo.Return_Invoice
After Insert
AS
declare @qty int
set nocount on

BEGIN
    set @qty= (Select RI.quantity FROM Return_Invoice RI where Item_code=yourcode)
    Update Product_Warehouse set  Quantity=Quantity-@qty where  Item_code=yourcode
END
GO
```

Comment: item_code is the relational key between your tables. So while you update your "Return_Invoice" table , you must know the item_code if you want to trigger in "product_warehouse"

Comment: This question is tagged Oracle. This is not Oracle syntax.

Comment: @Ben.. i am executin this query in Oracle Apex... so thats why i tagged  Oracle